# Allign image and text

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have text "Helloooooooooooooooo" at the bottom of the image but the image should be in the center of text.

Expected output:

```
            IMG
Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

Currently wrong output:

```
IMG
Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

What can I try?

```html
<div>
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/60x60"><br>
  <span style="">Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center` will center an `img`. Add that to the parent, and add `display: inline-block` if you want the parent on the left side of the screen contained to the max width of either the text or the `img`. Or remove it if you want the parent to occupy the full width of the container and the text/`img` centered relative to that width.

```html
<div style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/60x60"><br>
  <span style="">Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `img` to `display: block`, then set `margin: auto`.

```
img { display: block; margin: auto; }
```